# SwiftUI, using trailing with boolean on .padding

Tags: swift, swiftui

New to SwiftUI. I want to perform a `.slide` animation using `.padding`:

I was wondering, Why can't i use this code to use .trailing:

```
.padding(.trailing, self.showDetails ? 1000 : 100)
```

> result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Int' and 'CGFloat'

P.S: This is how i execute the animation, initially:

```
Image("close_x").onTapGesture {                   
      withAnimation(.spring()) {
         showDetails.toggle()
      }

      sliderValue +=  1

}
```

Comment: Can you please add minimal reproducible code?

Comment: @RajaKishan, Make a VStack, and Add padding to it with onTapGesture

Comment: Still not able to reproduce.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Try adding more context and preferably a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you send a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think the problem is in the animation since it should work

like this example compile and work

```
    struct CustomView: View {
   
    @State var showDetail: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
      Image(systemName: "plus")
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.spring()){
            showDetail.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding(.trailing, showDetail ? 10: 100)
    }
}
```

i think the problem that you are having is more on the sliderValue. Sliders require float points, try to remplace `sliderValue += 1` with `sliderValue += CGFloat(1)`

Comment: Using CGFLoat(100) like you suggested worked, thank you

Comment: The `CGFloat` should be inferred anyway based on the type of `sliderValue`, wherever it was previously defined. I don't understand how this solved the problem. I don't see anything else which changed to fix this error.

Comment: It worked on the padding line. I have no idea how really, As i'm fairly new to swift in general

Comment: on my test of the animation indeed George the CGFloat was inferred, we didn't have much information on his code, so i made a wild guess about the slider but anyway with this type of error there was obviously a conversion issue somewhere.